# UI5: VizFrame - are dashed lines possible?

Tags: sapui5

Are dotted or dashed lines possible with VizFrame [`sap.viz.ui5.controls.VizFrame`] (in case of line charts, in my case `timeseries_line`)? If yes, how? If no, are there workarounds or alternatives?
Is it possible to change between solid and dashed over time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible, please look [here](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/docs/vizdocs/#reference/chartProperty/Charts/Line%20%20(3)/Line%20Chart/), choose plotArea and after that dataPointStyle. You should set lineType property to "dotted".